# matplotlib: get precise point of intersection

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2]
y1 = [11, 0]
y2 = [0, 5]

np_x = np.array(x)
np_y1 = np.array(y1)
np_y2 = np.array(y2)

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(np_y2 - np_y1))).flatten()

isect = zip(np_x[idx], np_y1[idx])

for x,y in isect:
    print(f'({x}, {y})')


plt.plot(np_x, np_y1)
plt.plot(np_x, np_y2)
plt.show()
```

the below is the graph of the above code.
however, the intersection being printed is (1,11)
I suppose because it is rounded up to a whole number.
how do i get the precise intersection points? ie something like (1.7, 3.8)

thank you

[image]

Comment: What about increasing the density of the samples i.e.,
`x = np.linspace(1, 2, 1000)
y1 = np.linspace(11, 0, 1000)
y2 = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)`?

Comment: Why bothering get the point in the array, it is mathematically solvable no?

Comment: @BookSword i just made a simple example to illustrate the limitation with my current algo for finding the exact intersection

i have 100s of data points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use denser array of values to get more precise result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Line1, (x, y1)
x = [1, 2]
y1 = [11, 0]

# Line2, (x, y2), common x
y2 = [0, 5]

# Create denser array values, here 100 items for each line
np_x = np.linspace(x[0], x[1], 100)
np_y1 = np.linspace(y1[0], y1[1], 100)
np_y2 = np.linspace(y2[0], y2[1], 100)

# Find the indices of array elements that are non-zero, grouped by element.
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(np_y2 - np_y1))).flatten()

isect = zip(np_x[idx], np_y1[idx])

for xi, yi in isect:
    print(f'({xi}, {yi})')
    plt.scatter(xi, yi, color="red", s=50)

plt.plot(np_x, np_y1)
plt.plot(np_x, np_y2)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
(1.6868686868686869, 3.4444444444444446)
```

Graphic output for checking:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

Interpolate your data to get more points, substract one y-array from the other, calculate the sign of the difference for each point, detect when the sign changes, grab the index of this change: that's the intersection index.

Edit: the difference between my answer and the two others is that mine still works if you data is not affine.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 1000

x = np.array([1, 2])
y1 = np.array([11, 0])
y2 = np.array([0, 5])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y1)
ax.plot(x, y2)
fig.show()

xi = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], N)
yi1 = np.interp(xi, x, y1)
yi2 = np.interp(xi, x, y2)
difference_sign = np.sign(yi1 - yi2)
sign_variation = np.diff(difference_sign)
intersection_index = np.argmax(sign_variation != 0)
xinter, yinter = xi[intersection_index], yi1[intersection_index]

ax.scatter(xinter, yinter, marker="D", zorder=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The intersection point of the two straight lines should be mathematically solvable. It's `(-(np_x[0]*(np_y1[1]-np_y2[1]) + np_x[1]*(np_y2[0]-np_y1[0]))/(np_y1[0]-np_y1[1]-np_y2[0]+np_y2[1]), -(y1[1]*y2[0]-y1[0]*y2[1])/(np_y1[0]-np_y1[1]-np_y2[0]+np_y2[1]))`.

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**

You can find the result analytically by finding the slopes and intersections of each linear function that crosses each pair of points you provided. With that the exact point of intersection is: **x = 27/16 = 1.6875**;  **y = 55/16 = 3.4375**.

**Using sympy to find exact intersection**

```py
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def slope(X, Y):
    """Find the slope of the line that crosses two points"""
    return (Y[1] - Y[0])/(X[1] -X[0])

# provided data
x0 = np.array([1, 2])
y1 = np.array([11, 0])
y2 = np.array([0, 5])

# symbols to solve equations
x = sp.Symbol('x')
y = sp.Symbol('y')
b = sp.symbols('b')

# slopes
M1, M2 = slope(x0, y1), slope(x0, y2)

# solving for the intersection of each line to y-axis
# i.e, solving 'y = M*x + b' for b, for each line
b1 = sp.solve(sp.Eq(M1*x0[0] + b, y1[0]))
b2 = sp.solve(sp.Eq(M2*x0[0] + b, y2[0]))

# solving for the intersection x between the two lines
# then finding y(x)
x_intersec = sp.solve(sp.Eq(M1*x + b1[0], M2*x + b2[0]))
y_intercec = M1*x_intercept[0] + b1[0]
print(x_intersec[0], y_intersec)

# result: (1.68750000000000, 3.43750000000000)

# ploting
plt.plot(x0, y1)
plt.plot(x0, y2)
plt.scatter(x_intercept[0], y_intercept, color="red", s=60, zorder=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]